# ESP8266 failing to receive message over MQTT via AWS IoT Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, mqtt, esp8266, aws-iot

I'm using [PubSubClient](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) per [this example](https://github.com/debsahu/ESP-MQTT-AWS-IoT-Core) to connect to AWS IoT. Specifically, I'm trying to use [AWS IoT Fleet Provisioning](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-automate-onboarding-of-iot-devices-to-aws-iot-core-at-scale-with-fleet-provisioning/), which involves subscribing and publishing to some special `$aws/` topics.

The connection is being established correctly, and CloudWatch logs show successful `Connect`, `Subscribe`, `Publish-In` and `Publish-Out` events. However, whenever the MCU receives a message, it appears to drop the connection. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging PubSubClient showed that the underlying `WiFiClientSecure` instance was losing connection due to the following error:

```
BR_ERR_TOO_LARGE: Incoming record is too large to be processed, or buffer is too small for the handshake message to send.
```

The message I was receiving was about 4 KB, so I had to add the following:

```c
  wifi_ = new WiFiClientSecure();
  wifi_->setBufferSizes(4096, 512);
```

From there, it turned out PubSubClient had its own buffer, which I also had to raise:

```c
  mqtt_ = new PubSubClient(*wifi_);
  mqtt_->setBufferSize(4096);
```

Making these changes allowed me to receive these messages from AWS IoT successfully.